# Flutter flutter_background_service app resuming issue

Tags: flutter, kotlin, foreground-service

I am using the flutter package **flutter_background_service**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example

when the app is resuming, I have this infinite message

```
Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: plugins.flutter.io/sensors/accelerometer. Response ID XXXX
```

Flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.1526], locale fr-CD)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.9.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you post your flutter doctor results?

Comment: @GabrieleSantoro I've edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61934900/11675817) and [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28651).

But unfortunately it's not fixed yet. Maybe this is a bug.